# Silverlight 4 MVVM ComboBox data binding is not being displayed

Tags: xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, combobox

I have a ComboBox with the following XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="CompanyComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompanyList, Mode=OneWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentCompany, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

> **Problem:**
>
> The selected option on 'company' is persisted, but never gets displayed on load. What's missing or going wrong, or what have I forgotten to do?

- CompanyList has data, and the ComboBox does get populated
- The selection on the ComboBox does save to the database via the TwoWayBinding
- [More code is on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/SJYGMzs0), the ViewModel and the Company class code.

I have tried the following suggestions, **that have so far not solve the issue**:

1. [Two-way bind a combobox to a simple string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729146/two-way-bind-a-combobox-to-a-simple-string-array) Order of ItemSource and SelectedValue properties on  were correct
2. [ComboBox.SelectedValue not updating from binding source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247413/wpf-combobox-selectedvalue-not-updating-from-binding-source) alternating between 'SelectedValue' and 'SelectedIndex' - neither works
3. [Silverlight 4 Combobox with selectedValue using MVVM-Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554174/silverlight-4-combobox-with-selectedvalue-using-mvvm-light) raising PropertyChanged before setting new value also didn't help
4. Adding/Removing 'IsEnabled="{Binding IsReady}' on the ComboBox didn't help either
5. Adding SelectedValuePath="Name" or ="Value" stopped the save from working

Comment: What do you mean with "The selected option on 'company' is persisted, but never gets displayed on load." ? Your combobox has no initial "selectedItem" (the box is empty until you click on it to open the dropdown) ?

Comment: By persissed I mean changes get saved to the database. Also correct there was no 'intiial selected item'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `Company.Equals()` method to return `true` if the object's data is the same.

By default, it only returns `true` if the two company objects being compared share the same spot in memory, and I am guessing that your `CurrentCompany` object does not point to an object in `CompanyList`, so the `SelectedItem` is being set to `null`

Answer (score 1):

Check that the instance assigned to CurrentCompany is the actual one contained in CompanyList and not a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
after populating CompanyList in your ViewModel, set the CurrentCompany to the first company, or a dummy item that says , or  depending on your context.

Answer (score 0):

Can we take a look at the view model please? Until this information is not present, may give following suspections.

1. CurrentCompany property is not public or is not a property.
2. View model doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
3. Setter of CurrentCompany property doesn't contain PropertyChanged event notification.